# How to get button code error if textbox empty ? VS 2017

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello I'm a newbie at this, I make a form in VS 2017, but there is something bugging me. What code to make button error if textbox is empty ?

its like
ID          (TextBox)
Password    (Textbox)
Button.. I want if someone didnt fill Id and password when they click button, it will pop up msgbox error that say id and password still empty.

Comment: Though i answered your question, but please read [ask] and take the [tour] and also do some research before posting

Comment: Why let them click the `Button` at all? You should start by disabling the `Button` by default. Next, write a method that tests whether both `TextBox` controls are populated and enables the `Button` if and only if they are. You would then call that method from the `TextChanged` event handler of each `TextBox`. The user can then only click the `Button` if they have populated both fields.

Comment: @jmcilhinney For you logic to implement, you need 3 parts: 1) Handler for password text box 2) Handler for user name text box 3) Helper procedure which will decide whether enable button or disable. But, there's more. If, besides these two text boxes, there will be more elements, how a user will get know, why the button is disabled? Did he forget something else except user name and password? It's simpler to have one event handler which will make all decisions.

Comment: @JohnyL, the best option depends on circumstances and also opinion but it sounds like this is a login form so I think that anyone who gets confused as to why a button is disabled if they haven't entered an ID and password probably shouldn't be trusted with a computer or any electrical device for that matter. Also, you can just have one event handler that does everything and still do as I suggested, i.e. handle the `TextChanged` event of both `TextBoxes` with the same method and put all the logic in there.

Comment: You might consider using the built-in [ErrorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a or condition. So check if one of the inputs is empty.

Try the below code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtId.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Id or password still empty")
    End If
End Sub
```